# Arduino + OLED power consumption

Tags: microcontroller, power

I'm building a project using the [SparkFun MicroView](http://sfe.io/p12923), which is essentially an ATMega328 + OLED display, and I'm trying to decide what size LiPo to use... I like the size/footprint of the [110mAh battery SparkFun offers](http://sfe.io/p731). However, I don't know how many amps to expect the MicroView to use. My project will be a simple handheld game, so I would like the battery to last at least 3-4 hours before needing a charge.

Doing the calculations: 0.11Ah / 4h = .0275A = 27.5mA. Is it reasonable for something like the ATMega328 + OLED display to draw around 27mA or less? I also designed my buttons with pull-down resistors, since they are normally open and I don't want them to draw current (albeit minute) while open.

Comment: I've seen these, they look like cool devices, but sadly for some reason there is very little explicit technical doucmentation (at least for current draw). Pretty odd because sparkfun is usually decent about that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run an ATMega328 at anything between 0.1mA and 20mA for only its core (I'm using an estimation from memory here, but there abouts) using the internal RC oscillator speeds. Lower clock speed = less processing power, but also lower power use.

So that will very much depend on the complexity of your program and how quickly it should run through that complexity.

The OLED is harder, because Sparkfun cleverly doesn't really tell us which display they are using, but for 48x64pixel RGB OLED, I would expect average use to be in the 20mA range. But this is just a very big ball-park guess, as I am not a super-expert on the stuff (so I might be off by a decent margin still). As much as the end-average use, even if you know the peak use or any other statistic, because an OLED display's power drain depends on how many pixels you use and how many colours for each pixel.

The best thing is to just measure what the display uses in your situation over a good span of time. Several minutes to an hour.

Using the Atmel datasheet you can make some predictions if you know at what speed it runs and using 3.7V (probably nearest curve will be 3.3V, so round up a little at least). Those sections are usually in the Chapter 24 to 32 region, somewhere at the back, called "Electrical Characteristics".

Also use at least 20% margin in your battery capacity to run time calculations, so you don't get disappointed when the actual battery is a bit off and/or starts aging, or might be defined at 10mA drain for a 110mAh type, where you drain 30mA, which would decrease that usable capacity.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did find that the OLED is rated at a draw of 10mA-20mA. [Source](http://sfe.io/p13003)

Comment: @andrewm1100 I'm glad I wasn't that far off. That might mean you should think about 2 to 4 hours on a 110mAh.